# execute SSIS or DTS package asynchronously from ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ssis

I need to load and execute SSIS or DTS packages ASYNCHRONOUSLY from ASP.NET C# page on click of a button and report the success or failure at the end of the execution and if it fails the details of the exception should be shown to the user. it needs to be asynchronous because job could take a long time to finish. user should also be able to cancel the execution of the package while it is running if he wishes to do so. there is also requirement to execute multiple packages in parallel and track the progress for each of them. is this possible to achieve OR too complicated to do it from ASP.NET? Please let me know if you have any sample code or links that do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have more than one pools, then you need a common database table and a separate class to handle this parallel execution with all the one you ask. Not an easy task, we have one like that but we have many hours of work on it and its very custom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by queuing up the user requests for DTS/SSIS package execution in a table and reading them in a windows service and executing them in parallel by spawning threads using ThreadPool class. it is working fine. thanks. the drawback of this approach is polling, to make it event driven, creating a WCF service and hosting it in a windows service would be best which I will try next. thanks for all your replies. btw, I can't use sql server agent, it is not allowed as per my company IT policy.

Answer (score 1):

A solution you might consider is to use SQLServer jobs.  You can set up the packages as jobs with or without a run schedule.  You can start, cancel, get job status and get failure information by running stored procedures and queries in the msdb system database.  You can run the procedures and queries from you ASP.NET C# page.

Running SSIS/DTS packages in jobs is a common approach.  And, this solution would allow you to use Management Studio to manage the jobs as well.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how does this work? the SSIS/DTS packages are stored on the webserver. do I need to create a job on the webserver? if so, do I need to install SQL components on it to create a job (not sure if the server policy in my company will allow this)? how the stored procedure will know about the job that is located somewhere else?

Comment: are you sure the SSIS / DTS are on the webserver?  They should be part of the DB...

Comment: yes, the SSIS/DTS packages are not located on the database, they are stored on the file system on webserver. If I need to create a job and call it using a stored procedure, then do I need to install any SQL components on the webserver? if not, I will have to go for the option in my original question.

Comment: To run SSIS on the *webserver* you'll need SSIS to be installed on the webserver (and SQL server licence for the web-server).  

Alternately if the SSIS packages are on the database, with a stored proc on the DB, then they can be called from the webserver with no SQL components on the webserver.

Comment: +1 the use of sql agent jobs. Use sp_start_job to launch an existing job, let the package write it's status to a custom table and show that in your aspx page.
Alternatively, you could use dtexec.exe to run the package from file in a thread, but that'll also need an installation of SSIS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Rhino ETL instead of SSIS. This is a fully-fledged ETL library which allows you to code your ETL jobs in C#.

Comment: ETL?? ahhh thank you Google:  **E** xtract **T** ransform **L** oad